# Visual Studio 22 Multiple Startup Projects

Tags: c#, asp.net, angular, visual-studio-2022

I`m using VS 2022 Professional 2022 (17.2.0).

I wanted to create a ASP.Net Core app with Angular in VS and used the Microsoft Tutorial for it. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/javascript/tutorial-asp-net-core-with-angular?view=vs-2022

When I want to start Multiple Project as once, only Angular CLI will start the ng start command, but the ASP.NET Core Project will never start.
When I disable the Angular Project inside, Multiple Startprojects, the .Net Core Console will start.

```
Creation started...
1>------ Build started: Project: ConverterBackend, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
2>------ Build started: Project: Converter, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
1>Analyzer tools are skipped to speed up the build. You can run the Build or Rebuild command to run the analyzer.
1>ConverterBackend -> C:\Optimization\Converter\ConverterBackend\bin\Debug\net6.0\ConverterBackend.dll
3>------ Deployment started: Project: Converter, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
```

Settings:

[image: Multiple Projects Startup]
[image: Config Manager]

[image: .NET Debug Settings]
[image: Visual Studio Bar]

proxy.conf.js

```
target: "https://localhost:7049",
```

launchSettings.json

```
"applicationUrl": "https://localhost:7049;https://localhost:5001",
```

I hope somebody has a Solution or run into the same Error once, cause I cant find anything about this.
Could this be an AV problem?

Solution:
If u ever run into this Problem Check Script Execution permissions and if the AV blocks something.

Comment: If I need to start multiple projects at once (and I have an Angular & web-API services), I would use docker for that. You can combine your dockerfiles in a docker-compose file and use it to start your application directly from VisualStudio. This makes also the deployment of your application easier.

Comment: @Dlyx This is an good Answer thanks you!

Comment: @Kaze did you solve this problem? I have the same as you. What do you mean by Script Execution permissions? [This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_execution_policies?view=powershell-7.3)?

Comment: By the way, I also posted the question on [visualstudio-docs](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/visualstudio-docs/issues/8700) repo on Github.

Comment: @chick3n0x07CC The fix that I used was 

Powershell:
```Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Scope CurrentUser```

.So u just had missing permissions on ur Windows for running scripts overall

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was also struggling with this and finally found a solution thanks to [this user](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1109248/can39t-start-frontend-and-backend-projects-at-the.html?childToView=1114979#answer-1114979). It might not be viable for everyone since it requires a **version downgrade** but I'll share it: I was using Node.js v18.12.1 (LTS at the time) (64-bit). I had installed it with [nvm for Windows](https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows). With this set up, OP problem is reproduced.

Then, I used nvm to switch to Node v16.18.1 (64-bit). With this change the frontend and backend run perfect as expected from the tutorial.

**Edit:**

Another [solution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1109248/can39t-start-frontend-and-backend-projects-at-the.html?childToView=1137669#comment-1137669) to avoid the downgrade is keep using Node.js v18.12.1 and just add `--host 0.0.0.0` to the `start` command in Angular `package.json`:

```
"start": "ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --ssl --ssl-cert %APPDATA%\\ASP.NET\\https\\%npm_package_name%.pem --ssl-key %APPDATA%\\ASP.NET\\https\\%npm_package_name%.key"
```

This works but I can't provide an explanation for why. But it requires adding a rule to the Windows firewall (you probably get a prompt asking you for permission).

Answer (score 1):

You have to start the ASP.Net Core app. In there you should have a Startup Class.
Go to Configure Services and add something like this:

services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration => { configuration.RootPath = "WebUI"; });

Then the Kestrel Server should start up with the SPA.

Comment: This has nothing todo with the Question or Solution

Answer (score 0):

I use two instances of VS open for this; each with a different start up project.

Comment: This is not a Solution for the problem... It works, but does not rly solve the problem that I ask about.

Comment: This solves the issue, which is running two projects at the same time and debugging them, but it's your question and ultimately you decide if this provided you with value.

Comment: This approach only works if the two startup projects do not share any libraries. If they do, the second one to start gets an error trying to access libraries that are already opened by the first process.