# Visual Studio multi-project solution won't start Web API project when debugging

Tags: visual-studio-2022, visual-studio-debugging

I have a Visual Studio 2022 solution with two projects.
One is an ASP.Net Core Web API project.
The other is a stand alone Angular TypeScript application.

[image]

On the solution properties page I have it configured to start "Multiple StartUp Projects" with the Web API starting up first so it can support the Angular application when it starts.

[image]

When I press F5 to debug the Angular console has been starting up pretty quickly:

[image]

But the backend Web API project console window will not open to build, compile and show the listening port anymore.

The lower left of Visual Studio says Ready but there seems to be some background tasks that have been running for like a half hour now:

[image]

Not sure what to do.

I guess I'll try a reboot at this point.

Comment: Try to change the create step of these two apps, and try to unselect "Add integration for empty ASP xxx"

Comment: And try to change the order of these two projects and try again.

Comment: I downgraded my Node.js per https://stackoverflow.com/a/74679184/9486312, which worked for me.